# Error --home not recognized while build python package

Tags: python, pip

I see the error below for this command. How can it be resolved?

**Command**

```
python3 setup.py develop --no-deps --home=/tmp/pip-target-8j_hopa9
```

**Error**

```
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help

    error: option --home not recognized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option `--home` for command `develop`:

```
$ python3 setup.py develop --help | grep -F -- --home
```